# Adding a XP field to the default user model

Tags: python, django

So in the last hour I've been struggling to implement a XP field to the default user model. I studied the django docs and I saw there are two ways to customize the authentication - either extending the User model, or changing it.

I've decided to just extend it, because I only need to add two or three more fields in the future. (I'm trying to add only this XP field rn so I can get how it should be done)

I thought I made it until I got this error:
'Manager' object has no attribute 'create_user'

As far as I know, this happens because the create_user method is bound to User, and I changed the model. Here's the line which creates the error:

```
user = Utilizator.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
```

So I'm doing it wrong.

Here's the code:
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Utilizator
from django.contrib import auth

# Create your views here.
def login(req):
    if req.method == 'POST':
        username = req.POST['username']
        password = req.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(req, user)
            messages.success(req, 'Acum eşti logat')
            return redirect('dashboard')
        else:
            messages.error(req, 'Numele de utilizator sau parola sunt greşite')
            return redirect('login')
        return
    else:
        return render(req, "../templates/pagini/login.html")
def register(req):
    if req.method == 'POST':
        first_name = req.POST['first_name']
        last_name = req.POST['last_name']
        username = req.POST['username']
        email = req.POST['email']
        password = req.POST['password']
        password2 = req.POST['password2']

        if password == password2:
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.error(req, 'Numele de utilizator deja există')
                return redirect('register')
            else:
                if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    messages.error(req, 'E-mailul este deja folosit')
                    return redirect('register')
                else:
                    user = Utilizator.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
                    user.save()
                    messages.success(req, 'Acum eşti logat')
                    return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.error(req, 'Parolele diferă')
            return redirect('register')
    else:
        return render(req, "../templates/pagini/register.html")
def dashboard(req):
    return render(req, "../templates/pagini/dashboard.html")
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Utilizator(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    xp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I have no idea if this is the right way to do it. I'm a beginner and I want to learn how it should be done.

So is it okay using this models.py? If it is, what should I change to views.py?

If it's not, can you teach me how I should do this whole thing? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. As you said, there are 2 main ways to extend `User`. 1) Create a new model and inherit from `AbstractUser` (complicated), or 2) Create a separate model with a 1-to-1 relationship (simpler, as you have done).

The basic implementation is to extend the `User` object with a `UserProfile`, and then making it accessible/autogenerate whenever `user.profile` is called.

Example:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """ Extends the User model with a UserProfile """
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userprofileAsUser')
    xp = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(self.user.username)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "user profile"
        verbose_name_plural = "user profiles"

def get_or_create_profile(user):
    profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    return profile

User.profile = property(get_or_create_profile)
```

Comment: Please consider adding a reference to [AutoOneToOneField](https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying#autoonetoonefield) to your answer.

Comment: How should the views.py look so I can use your code? I don't seem to make it work.